# Receive JSON request from PHP

Tags: php, json, extjs4, firebug

In firebug, in the POST tab i see the following;

```
JSON        

textfieldone "Alex"



Source
{"textfieldone :"Alex"}
```

But in the PARAMS tab i see

```
_dc 1341332451114
```

In my PHP code when i `print_r($_REQUEST);` i get

```
Array
(
    [_dc] => 1341332451114
)
```

and not the JSON, that was found in the POST tab. How could i solve this ?

I have no clue why this is hapenning, i have tried to debug this all day

**UPDATE PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pwd") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());

print_r($_REQUEST);
```

In firebug i see the above Responces under the url;

```
POST http://localhost/proj/php/result.php?_dc=1341332451114 200 OK 107ms
```

May i know what `?_dc=1341366375982` is. I am sending POST

**UPDATE 2**

EXT JS4 code

MODEL

```
Ext.define ('Mycomp.model.MyClass',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields:['textfieldone']

});
```

VIEW

```
Ext.define('Mycomp.view.user.MyClassView', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.myclassview',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'textfieldone',
                        fieldLabel: 'Contact Person Name'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
        this.buttons = [
                        {
                            text: 'Save',
                            name:'save',
                            action: 'save'
                        }
                    ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
Ext.define('Mycomp.controller.MyClass',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    stores:['MyClass'],
    models:['MyClass'],
    views:['MyClassView'],
    init: function(){
        this.control({          
            'myclassview button[action=save]': {
                click: this.myMethod
            }
        });         
        },
         myMethod: function(button, record) {

       var win    = button.up('window'),
           form   = win.down('form'), 
           values = form.getValues(),
           store = this.this.getmyClassStore(),
           model = store.model,
           record = model.create();


           record.set( values );
           store.add( record );
           win.close();
           store.sync(); 
}
});
```

STORE

```
Ext.define('Mycomp.store.Myclass',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'App.model.Myclass',

    proxy: {
        actionMethods : {
            create : 'POST'
        },
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/savetodb.php'

    }

});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not returning a 404?

Comment: I have added my PHP code above. and i am not getting a 404

Comment: How are you sending the data, where do they come from?

Comment: It looks like none of the POST data is being received, only the GET.

Comment: What should i do to send the POST data, it is actually there in the POST tab of firebug :S

Comment: @Dr.Molle the data comes from a form, i am using EXTjs4 for that

Comment: Post your javascript which is sending the post data

Comment: Also what is `print_r($_POST)`? It's possible `POST` is not being included in `REQUEST`?

Comment: @andrewtweber when i print `print_r($_POST)` i get `Array
(
)`

Comment: I have Added my EXTJS4 code for your reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to set your .php file headers to serve up JSON:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: This is for *sending* JSON *from* PHP. The question is about *receiving* JSON from the client in a POST request.

Comment: Whelp -- I'm lost. @Illep can you give me a quick write up of what files you have and their intended interactions.

Comment: I have included my Ext JS4 code in my question above. I have also made a change to JSON POST string above

Comment: Yeah... I agree with @andrewtweber -- I think for some reason $_REQUEST is only reading what is in the $_GET superglobal... Try: print_r($_POST) in your PHP file and I think you'll see your textfieldone information.

Comment: when i print `print_r($_POST`) i get `Array ( )`

Comment: you can control that with extjs, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code, it should resolve your problem:

```
<?php
   var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));
?>
```